# ActiveX event handlers in an HTA using JScript

Tags: events, activex, jscript, hta, activexobject

In C# I can write event handlers as follows:

```
var wdApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
wdApp.DocumentBeforeSave += (Document doc, ref bool saveAsUI, ref bool cancel) => {
   //do stuff here
};
```

In VBA/VB6, I can use static event handling:

```
Dim WithEvents wdApp As Word.Application

Private Sub wdApp_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    'do stuff here
End Sub
```

I would prefer to use dynamic event handling. However, in JScript, even when using static event handling with the syntax described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974564.aspx):

```
var wdApp = new ActiveXObject('Word.Application');
wdApp.Visible = true;

function wdApp::Quit() {
    window.alert('Quit');
};
```

it fails:

> 0x800a138f - JScript runtime error: Object expected

Also, static event handling is an option in VBA/VB6, because the declarations can be marked `Private`. However, in JScript, both the variable and the handler have to be declared in the global scope.

Two questions:

1. **How can I handle events of Automation-created objects with JScript in an HTA environment?**
   (Note: I know that it is possible in WSH using a prefix passed to `CreateObject`, and a function named `wdApp_Quit`, but I am looking for an HTA solution.)
2. **How can I do this without polluting the global scope?**

---

There is an older question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150814/how-to-handle-an-activex-event-in-javascript).

Comment: I've had a look but I can't get anything to work.  The WSH solution you mention uses "ConnectObject" and I've tried to use that in an HTA with the WScript.Shell but it's not working.  There is an unanswered question simialr to yours on MSDN since 2009 so it looks like it may not be possible.

Comment: Should be objectname::eventname.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974564.aspx

Comment: Event connection, as far as I've seen, depends on the WScript object, which is not present in the mshta.exe host (which runs HTAs). However, the mshta can call a javascript object, with the wscript.exe host, and get access to the WScript object. Would such solution be OK for you, or do it seem too ugly?

Comment: @EduardoPoço _Event connection, as far as I've seen, depends on the WScript object_ -- As I noted in my (edited) question, the Microsoft extensions to Javascript allow defining a global function of the form `varName::eventName() { }` which will be called on the `eventName` event for the global-scoped `varName` object. This mechanism is available in both WScript and in HTAs. But I would like something that doesn't require global function declarations and global variables; similar to the C# mechanism -- `wdApp` doesn't have to be a global variable in order to attach / remove handlers.

Comment: @EduardoPoço Gordon describes trying a similar solution without success in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713117/event-handlers-on-automation-objects-in-an-hta-using-javascript?noredirect=1#comment70718162_41713117), but it would be worthwhile as long as I don't have to declare the function and variable in global scope.

Comment: This is getting too complicated for me but when you said that it could be running before the wdApp is created I remembered that I saw a connect object example on devguru that uses sleep before to wait half a second for the object to be created. I don't know if you can use settimeout but have a look at the code below.

Comment: objWord = WScript.CreateObject("Word.Application")
WScript.ConnectObject(objWord, "objWord_")

objWord.visible = true
blnWordVisible = true

while (blnWordVisible)
{
    WScript.Sleep(500)
}

function objWord_Quit ()
{
    blnWordVisible = false
    WScript.Echo("You quit Word.")
}

function objWord_DocumentChange ()
{
    WScript.Echo("You switched documents.")
}

Comment: It works! self.setTimeout("function wdApp::Quit() {window.alert('Quit');};", 500)
I used your first bit of code and wrapped the wdApp::Quit() function in a settimeout and itworked without errors.

Comment: @Gordon RE: `setTimeout` see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41888383/111794).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error appears to be because

1. In Javascript/JScript [function declarations are evaluated first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), before the variable is initialized. It's as if the code was written thus:

   ```
    var wdApp;
    function wdApp::Quit() { ... }
    wdApp = new ActiveXObject('Word.Application');
   ```
2. The Microsoft JScript parser interprets the specially-named declaration (with `::`) as an instruction to attach the function as an event handler.
3. But at the point of the declaration, the handler cannot be attached to the object referred to by `wdApp`, because `wdApp` at that point is still `undefined`. Hence, the error.

The solution is to force the function declaration to be evaluated after `wdApp` is initialized. This can be done in one of three ways<sup>1</sup>:

1. Since the function declaration is hoisted only to within the function scope, wrap the function declaration in an IIFE:

   ```
    var wdApp = new ActiveXObject('Word.Application');
    (function() {
        function wdApp::Quit() {
            //do stuff here
        }
    })();
   ```
2. Create the declaration using some sort of string -> code mechanism -- `eval`, `setTimeout` with a string, `window.execScript`, or `new Function`:

   ```
    var wdApp = new ActiveXObject('Word.Application');
    eval('function wdApp::Quit() { ... }`);
   ```
3. Initialize the variable before the current `SCRIPT` block. Most of the examples in the [Scripting Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974564.aspx) article do this by setting the `id` property on some element before the `SCRIPT` block:

> ```
> <object progid="ordersystem.clsorder" id="myorder" events="true"/>
> <script language="jscript">
>     function myorder::onNew() {
>       WScript.Echo("new order received from myorder")
>     }
> //...
> ```

but this could also be done using multiple `SCRIPT` blocks:

```
    <SCRIPT>
        var wdApp = new ActiveXObject('Word.Application');
    </SCRIPT>
    <SCRIPT>
        function wdApp::Quit() {
            //do stuff here
        }
    </SCRIPT>
```

---

As far as polluting the global namespace, only the third variant requires `wdApp` to be in the global namespace; the other two variants can be wrapped in an IIFE.

---

<sup>1. Technically, there is a fourth way under IE and HTAs, but it involves non-standard HTML instead of non-standard Javascript; But it can only be used if the object is declared using the HTML `OBJECT` tag, not with `new ActiveXObject( ... )`.</sup>

```
<script for="wdApp" event="Quit">
    //do stuff here
</script>
```

Comment: so, :: only works with eval, or evalscript, is that it?

Comment: @EduardoPoço Or any form of string evaluation -- [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), or [`new Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

Comment: @EduardoPoço It seems it's also possible to wrap in an IIFE. Updated my answer.